# In which folder are the product images in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I'm trying to migrate a local project to the server and when trying to get the images in pub / media / catalog / product they just don't appear. Where does magento physically store images? i tried to search but all i found were images from sample-data. Where are the physical images of the products? and without using the magento csv tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pub/media/catalog/product

The images are stored in subfolders based on the name of the image. salt.jpg would be in pub/media/catalog/product/s/a/salt.jpg. If they didn't get migrated you may need to do the following:

1. cd root_folder/pub    (on the old server)
2. tar -cvf media.tar media/*
3. move the media.tar file to the root_folder/pub (on the new server)
4. tar --skip-old-files -xvf media.tar
5. php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Comment: I follow the path of the images, but they are simply not there, all I find are images from the sample data. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: cd root folder/pub (on the old server)
tar -cvf media.tar media/*
move the media.tar file to the pub directory on the new server
tar --skip-old-files -xvf media.tar
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize